# Migrate custom AngularJS filter from 1.2.28 to 1.4.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a complex JSON response that is iterated over using ng-repeat. Only a relatively small subset of the attributes within the result set are displayed on the screen, so filtering of the results should be restricted to values the user can actually see, otherwise the filtering behavior would be confusing to the end-user.

Since one of the attributes I wish to filter on is a deeply nested array, a custom filter was needed since the built-in AngularJS filterFilter does not iterate over the array elements to the best of my knowledge.

I was able to get this working some time back in AngularJS v1.2.28, but unfortunately it appears to break during a migration to v1.4.3. I have not spent time to isolate where in the release cadence this functionality broke however.

I have not found any helpful information in the migration guides that would indicate what has changed. All I know is that the actual/expected parameters to the filter receive different values in the latest major version of AngularJS, which leads to the failure.

### ng-repeat filter expression:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | list_filter:{establishment: {id: filterText, names: [{name: filterText}], locations: [{streetAddress1: filterText, streetAddress2: filterText, city: filterText, stateProvince: filterText, postalCode: filterText}]}}">
```

### Example data structure of a single element:

```
data = [{
id: 234567,
name: 'John Doe',
establishment: {
  id: 067915959,
  locations: [{
    id: '134B030365F5204EE05400212856E994',
    type: 'postal',
    streetAddress1: 'P O BOX 900',
    city: 'Grover',
    stateProvince: 'CA',
    postalCode: '902340900',
    isoCountryCode: 'US',
    region: 'MONROE'
  }, {
    id: '999B030365F4204EE05400212856E991',
    type: 'postal',
    streetAddress1: '2590 Atlantic Ave',
    city: 'Fredricks',
    stateProvince: 'VA',
    postalCode: '45487',
    isoCountryCode: 'US',
    region: 'MONROE'
  }],
  names: [{
    name: 'Grover Central School Dst',
    type: 'PRIMARY'
  }, {
    name: 'Grover Central School Dst',
    type: 'MARKETING'
  }, {
    name: 'Grover CENTRAL SCHOOL DISTRICT',
    type: 'LEGAL'
  }]
}
}];
```

### Supporting Plunker Examples:

- Plunker for version 1.2.28:
  http://plnkr.co/edit/KD1MmNMBEhO7X2v9yK4S?p=info
- Plunker for version
  1.4.3: http://plnkr.co/edit/OmPOOwRWCHuPutUtWOcC?p=info

### Edit:

The issue appears to be directly related to the changes introduced in v1.3.6.

Comment: From debugging your second plunker it is evident that in latest angular they introduced DeepCompare. So perhaps some of the work from `list_filter` is already done

Comment: Not to go too much into debugging Angular i'd re-implement `list_filter` using ability to pass a function instead of expression to `$filter` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: It appears the issue may be related to the fact that an implicit AND condition is now being applied but was previously an implicit OR, which is what is desired in my case. An enhancement to explicitly set this logic would be required to use the built in filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue is related to the fact that an implicit AND condition is now being applied but was previously an implicit OR, which is what is desired in my case. You can import the old version as a separate filter, if the old behavior is desired.